# Unexpected RPM conflict on %config(noreplace) files

Tags: linux, unix, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm creating my own **RPM** using `rpmbuild`.
My RPM **contains config files** which should **never get overridden**, even if the RPM contains a new version of these config files.

To archive this, I tagged these with

```
%config(noreplace) /opt/mypackage/etc/*
```

in the spec file.

According to the documentation and [this site](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html), a locally modified file will never get overridden in this case which is exactly what I want.

However, when doing the following operations:

1. Install version 1 of the RPM
2. Change configuration file `etc/myconfig`
3. Update package with version 2 of the RPM

**I'm getting a conflict:**

```
$ rpm --prefix ~/rpmroot/ -ih dist/mypackage-1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm
########################################### [100%]
file /home/user/rpmroot/mypackage/etc/myconfig from install of mypackage-1.0.2-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mypackage-1.0.1-1.x86_64
```

**Questions:**

- How can this conflict be explained? (I'd expect that the new version of the config file would be stored as `myconfig.rpmnew` and the existing remains untouched)
- What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE (additional information)**

The output of `rpm -qcp dist/mypackage-1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm` is:

```
/opt/mypackage/etc/config1.xml
/opt/mypackage/etc/config2.xml
/opt/mypackage/etc/run.sh
/opt/mypackage/etc/config3.xml
```

The complete `%files` section:

```
%files
%defattr(0444,root,root)
/opt/mypackage/java/*

#dba
%defattr(0444,root,root)
/opt/mypackage/dba/sql/*
%defattr(0555,root,root)
/opt/mypackage/dba/script/*

#srv
%defattr(0555,root,root)
/opt/mypackage/srv/bin/*
/opt/mypackage/srv/lib/*

#etc
%defattr(0664,root,root)
%config(noreplace) /opt/mypackage/etc/*
```

Comment: So odd that the "(noreplace)" feature is not documented ... almost the expected behavior in my book when you go through the trouble to say "%config" ...

Comment: It's documented, but not well: http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Spec (and also have a look at the unofficial, but helpful site: http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html )

Comment: Yes, I saw the unofficial, thats the only one that came up in my search (and your question).  Last night was the first time we tried `noreplace`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If* this is actually your issue, you may kick yourself ...

I think this may be just because you are "installing" and not "upgrading"
replace `-ih` with `-Uh`

I created a test RPM with similar setup, here are the results:

With -ih as you did

> $ sudo rpm --prefix ~/rpmroot/ -ih
>   /home/nhed/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ptst-1.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
>
> ##################################### [100%]    file /home/nhed/rpmroot/etc/a from install of ptst-1.1.0-1.x86_64 conflicts
>
> with file from package ptst-1.0.0-1.x86_64    file
>   /home/nhed/rpmroot/etc/b from install of ptst-1.1.0-1.x86_64 conflicts
>   with file from package ptst-1.0.0-1.x86_64    file
>   /home/nhed/rpmroot/etc/c from install of ptst-1.1.0-1.x86_64 conflicts
>   with file from package ptst-1.0.0-1.x86_64

With -Uh

> $ sudo rpm --prefix ~/rpmroot/ -Uh
>   /home/nhed/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ptst-1.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
>
> ##################################### [100%]
>
> warning: /home/nhed/rpmroot/etc/a created as /home/nhed/rpmroot/etc/a.rpmnew
>
> ##################################### [100%]

Comment: if you have tons of files under `/opt/mypackage/etc/` it sounds like you can make a "manifest" file in the %install rule (or earlier) that will find all those files and prefix them with the `%config(norplace)` directive, then pass the manifest with '-f' to `%files`

Comment: You're right, %config can only be followed by one filename, but I think a filename with wildcards is allowed. Otherwise, they would most probably not being packaged - or I would expect an error message. Nevertheless, I tried this out - it does not make any difference, the conflict remains. (BTW, the book http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s05s03.html also shows %config with wildcards)

Comment: @MRalwasser Can we see the rest of your %files section?  Also can you paste the output of `rpm -qcp dist/mypackage-1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: @MRalwasser fascinated enough I ran a test and updated my answer

Comment: Wow, thanks! That was indeed the problem. I thought that -i is a synonym for -U in case the package is already installed in an older version. Never expected that this could cause such an error. How did you find this error without knowing what I exactly typed?

Comment: @MRalwasser your paste with the error shows your rpm command line with "-ih", and I tried to reproduce exactly what you did so I also made my package relocatable (though I usually don't bother).

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's part of my question - very attentive! Yes, I am also using relocation within my package.