# rpm %config(noreplace) override with %config

Tags: linux, rpm, rpm-spec

In my rpm I have a full directory that I want to tag with %config(noreplace).  There is a file in that directory that I want to replace on every install with the latest from the rpm, using the semantics from %config.

Using the guide here: http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html, I tried the following:

```
%files
%config(noreplace) /my/saved/dir/*
%config /my/saved/dir/file1
```

and

```
%files
%config /my/saved/dir/file1
%config(noreplace) /my/saved/dir/*
```

hoping that the specific command would override the glob, but it didn't work.  Is there any RPM like command that I can use to force the %config behaviour on a file that's nested under a %config(noreplace) directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From:
http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html

> There is a restriction to the %config directive, and that restriction
>   is that no more than one filename may follow the %config. This means
>   that the following example is the only allowable way to specify config
>   files:
>
> ```
> %config /etc/foonly
> ```
>
> Note that the full path to the file, as it is installed at build time, is required.

However you can craft that list dynamically in %install section:

```
%install
echo '%dir /etc' >> list.txt
echo '%config(noreplace) /etc/foo' >> list.txt
# use for-loop or any other shell scripting technique

%files -f list.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The assumption is that every file in the package is listed in the *%files* section (list) of *.spec* file **exactly once**. I bet when you were running `rpmbuild` there was the following line in the output

```
warning: File listed twice: /my/saved/dir/file1
```

The solution is to list configuration file (which you want to be always overwritten) **only once and with proper directive** i.e. *%config(noreplace)*. This is no matter if it is specified directly or indirectly through wildcard character.

The statement referenced in msuchy's answer

> There is a restriction to the %config directive, and that restriction
>   is that no more than one filename may follow the %config.

must be from distant past for there are examples of spec files using wildcard characters in *%config* directive as early as in year [2008](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=445202).

The problem is not in using wildcard characters per se. The problem is that one and the same file is listed twice (once directly, and once indirectly as a result of usage of wildcard character) with different *%config* directives (once with plain *%config* and once with *%config(noreplace)*). Your test – changing order of these two declarations – and the result you observe suggests that *rpm* merges these two declarations into one *%config(noreplace)*. This would explain why the order of declarations does not matter. However, as I wrote above, the assumption is that every file is listed exactly once and this could be the reason I couldn't find any information on what is supposed to happen when some file is listed more than once.

Please note, that the file specified with *%config(noreplace)* must have changed – **in the package** – between the version already installed and the newer version being installed for *.rpmnew* files to be written – see [.rpmnew file not created on package upgrade?](https://serverfault.com/q/672625/1809)

Please be also aware that installation of newer version of some package is not treated like updating the package – see [Unexpected RPM conflict on %config(noreplace) files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18743779/95735)

Below are spec files for those wanting to try themselves.

*mypackage-old.spec*:

```
Summary: old version
Name: mypackage
Version: 1
Release: 1
License: BSD

%description
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610487/

%prep

%build

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/foo
echo 'replace' > %{buildroot}/foo/replace
echo 'noreplace' > %{buildroot}/foo/noreplace

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}


%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%config /foo/replace
%config(noreplace) /foo/*
```

*mypackage-new.spec*:

```
Summary: new version
Name: mypackage
Version: 2
Release: 1
License: BSD

%description
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610487/

%prep

%build

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/foo
echo 'new replace' > %{buildroot}/foo/replace
echo 'new noreplace' > %{buildroot}/foo/noreplace

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
# declaration A    
%config /foo/replace    
# declaration B
%config(noreplace) /foo/*
```

The result with RPM version 4.14.0 is the same no matter what order we place declarations A and B above:

```
% rpmbuild -ba ./mypackge-old.spec
% rpmbuild -ba ./mypackge-new.spec
% sudo rpm -i ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/mypackage-1-1.x86_64.rpm
% echo modified >> /foo/replace
% echo modified >> /foo/noreplace
% sudo rpm -U ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/mypackage-2-1.x86_64.rpm
warning: /foo/noreplace created as /foo/noreplace.rpmnew
warning: /foo/replace created as /foo/replace.rpmnew
```