# rpm %config not working as expected on package update

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

```
%files
%config /etc/somedir/*
%config /usr/bin/binary


%Postun
rm -rf %{_sysconfdir}/%{name}
rm -rf %{_bindir}/%{name}
```

I have the above lines in my spec files, and my expected result is when I update the package I want to overwrite any changes that was wrote on disk in /etc/somedir and its subdirectories and /usr/bin/binary and if there was no changes then dont do anything. -- got that info from

[https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejw35/docs/rpm_config.html) 
and 
[rpm %config(noreplace) override with %config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610487/rpm-confignoreplace-override-with-config)

**but actual result is:**
when I update the package, it completely deletes the /etc/somdir and /usr/bin/binary completely. I am not sure if i understood the documentation wrong or what! I am new to rpmbuild so please help!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove:

```
%Postun
rm -rf %{_sysconfdir}/%{name}
rm -rf %{_bindir}/%{name}
```

And it should do what you want.

It leaves you with:

```
%files
%config /etc/somedir/*
%config /usr/bin/binary
```

Marking the binary is hackish way. I am not sure why you are doing that. I would go with:

```
%files
%dir /etc/somedir
%config /etc/somedir/*
/usr/bin/binary
```

Comment: awesome, thank you very much that worked great. and I took your advice on the binary.